# CSS sliding panel visible by default, sliding on mouseout/mouseover

Tags: css, panel

My application needs a sliding panel for menus.
Following code produces a panel that is almost hidden at the bottom of the page, it slides in on mouseover and slides back to bottom on mouseout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    /* Panel */
    .panel-bottom {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      bottom: -60px;
      width: 100vw;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
      font-size: 20px;
      /* Transition */
      transition: bottom 1s;
      -webkit-transition: bottom 1s;
    }

    /* Slide in on mouseover */
    .panel-bottom:hover {
      bottom: 0px;
    }

    /* Hide on mouseout */
    .panel-bottom:not(:hover) {
      bottom: -60px;
    }

    .panel-bottom span,
    .panel-top span {
      margin: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Slider</h1>
  <div class="panel-bottom">
    <span><a href="#">Option-A</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Option-B</a></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/Samwise_71/pen/NWJZXXO

Now I want to change the panels behaviour as follows:

- The Panel should be visible by default.
- The visible panel should stay visible on mouseover
- The visible panel should slide to bottom on mouseout, only panels top edge stays at bottom of page.
- The hidden panel should slide in again on mouseover.

I can make the panel visible with

```
.panel-bottom { bottom: 0px; }
```

but then the mouseout rule will hide it immediately, if mouse is not over the panel.

I think to start with a visible panel the mouseout rule should only be applied after mouseover (when mouse is already over the panel).

Is there a CSS-only way to get a sliding panel that is visible by default and hides on mouseout?

Comment: Note that no major browser has needed the -webkit prefix in a long, long time.